# viewWillAppear method is not executing code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i came across this problem, my code in the `viewWillAppear` method is not executed when my view is shown. I google it somewhere and i think the problem in the `Class Identity`, since i have a tab view controller in my view, so the class identity to both the view and the tab view controller should be the same. Where to find the code identity? i can't figure it out. Thanx in advance for any helpful information.

Comment: Is that view the root view of a view controller that is part of tabViewController.viewControllers? If so, where does this view come from: loadView or a nib file? Also, how did you declare your viewWillAppear method and where do you put it, in the view controller or an NSView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following to determine wether `viewWillAppear` isn't firing properly, or something in your code within it isn't working.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
}
```